# How to detect when a specific Android app goes to the background?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an app that will launch, or show a notification or a popup when **another** specific app goes to the background.
For example:

- User launches app A
- User uses app A
- User puts app A in the background, either by pressing the home button or back button or launching another app
- My app detects that and launches itself or shows a popup or whatever

Is there a way to do this and if there is, without killing the battery?

Again, the app is **not my app**.

Answer (score 1):

In your app **A** put the below code in a class:

```
public class Foreground implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

public static final long CHECK_DELAY = 500;
public static final String TAG = Foreground.class.getName();

public interface Listener {

    public void onBecameForeground();

    public void onBecameBackground();

}

private static Foreground instance;

private boolean foreground = false, paused = true;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private List<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener>();
private Runnable check;

/**
 * Its not strictly necessary to use this method - _usually_ invoking
 * get with a Context gives us a path to retrieve the Application and
 * initialise, but sometimes (e.g. in test harness) the ApplicationContext
 * is != the Application, and the docs make no guarantees.
 *
 * @param application
 * @return an initialised Foreground instance
 */
public static Foreground init(Application application) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Foreground();
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(instance);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(Application application) {
    if (instance == null) {
        init(application);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get(Context ctx) {
    if (instance == null) {
        Context appCtx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        if (appCtx instanceof Application) {
            init((Application) appCtx);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Foreground is not initialised and " +
                        "cannot obtain the Application object");
    }
    return instance;
}

public static Foreground get() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Foreground is not initialised - invoke " +
                        "at least once with parameterised init/get");
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean isForeground() {
    return foreground;
}

public boolean isBackground() {
    return !foreground;
}

public void addListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    paused = false;
    boolean wasBackground = !foreground;
    foreground = true;

    if (check != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(check);

    if (wasBackground) {
        Log.i(TAG, "went foreground");
        for (Listener l : listeners) {
            try {
                l.onBecameForeground();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Listener threw exception!", exc);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "still foreground");
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    paused = true;

    if (check != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(check);

    handler.postDelayed(check = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (foreground && paused) {
                foreground = false;
                Log.i(TAG, "went background");
                for (Listener l : listeners) {
                    try {
                        l.onBecameBackground();
                        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
                        if (intent != null) {
                            // We found the activity now start the activity
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.package.name"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception exc) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Listener threw exception!", exc);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "still foreground");
            }
        }
    }, CHECK_DELAY);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
}
```

}

Now in onCreate method of Application.class put the code:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Foreground.init(this);
}
```

You have to set your app's package name in onActivityPaused() method.
Thanks